# JS Exception in Application Insight

Tags: javascript, azure, .net-6.0, azure-application-insights

I have a .net 6 web application and I am trying to find how can I get JS exceptions showing up in console to get logged in application insight.

I have tried to find out but struggling to get anything which can help.

I have successfully been able to send my nlogs, sql, captured in AI but unable to get the same done for JS exceptions.

Please let me know if any additional details from my end is required.

CSProj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="bundleconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="bundleconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="3.2.449" />   
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.7.34" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.SqlServer" Version="1.7.34" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate" Version="6.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.5">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.6.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.DownstreamApi" Version="2.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="5.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core" Version="2022.3.1109" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.16" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="" />
    <ProjectReference Include="" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Content\kendo\2022\" />
    <Folder Include="Scripts\Bootstrap\" />
    <Folder Include="Scripts\kendo\2022\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\lib\pages\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Set up

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) => module.EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true);
```

After normal AI setup one error I am still seeing in my console
[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I am still trying to find a way to get this done (JS exception to AI). Apart from this post my app insight set up I am getting the error "Failed to initialize AppInsights JS SDK: Cannot load Application Insights SDK, no instrumentation key was provided. r.warnToConsole @ Logging.ts:206"

Comment: 2 separate issues

Comment: Share your `.csproj` and code file where you are configuring AppInsights.

Comment: I have also made changes to have nlogs which is working fine so those references are also in csproj

Comment: What does `DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule` contain ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254285/discussion-between-lucky-and-harshitha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track JS Exceptions in `Application Insights`,
add the below JS in `Layout.cshtml` in head tag.

I have taken references from this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-sdk?tabs=javascriptwebsdkloaderscript#1-add-the-javascript-code) and added the JS.

- Add either ConnectionString or Instrumentationkey.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   !function (v, y, T) { var S = v.location, k = "script", D = "instrumentationKey", C = "ingestionendpoint", I = "disableExceptionTracking", E = "ai.device.", b = "toLowerCase", w = (D[b](), "crossOrigin"), N = "POST", e = "appInsightsSDK", t = T.name || "appInsights", n = ((T.name || v[e]) && (v[e] = t), v[t] || function (l) { var u = !1, d = !1, g = { initialize: !0, queue: [], sv: "6", version: 2, config: l }; function m(e, t) { var n = {}, a = "Browser"; return n[E + "id"] = a[b](), n[E + "type"] = a, n["ai.operation.name"] = S && S.pathname || "_unknown_", n["ai.internal.sdkVersion"] = "javascript:snippet_" + (g.sv || g.version), { time: (a = new Date).getUTCFullYear() + "-" + i(1 + a.getUTCMonth()) + "-" + i(a.getUTCDate()) + "T" + i(a.getUTCHours()) + ":" + i(a.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + i(a.getUTCSeconds()) + "." + (a.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1e3).toFixed(3).slice(2, 5) + "Z", iKey: e, name: "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights." + e.replace(/-/g, "") + "." + t, sampleRate: 100, tags: n, data: { baseData: { ver: 2 } } }; function i(e) { e = "" + e; return 1 === e.length ? "0" + e : e } } var e, n, f = l.url || T.src; function a(e) { var t, n, a, i, o, s, r, c, p; u = !0, g.queue = [], d || (d = !0, i = f, r = (c = function () { var e, t = {}, n = l.connectionString; if (n) for (var a = n.split(";"), i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { var o = a[i].split("="); 2 === o.length && (t[o[0][b]()] = o[1]) } return t[C] || (t[C] = "https://" + ((e = (n = t.endpointsuffix) ? t.location : null) ? e + "." : "") + "dc." + (n || "services.visualstudio.com")), t }()).instrumentationkey || l[D] || "", c = (c = c[C]) ? c + "/v2/track" : l.endpointUrl, (p = []).push((t = "SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details)", n = i, o = c, (s = (a = m(r, "Exception")).data).baseType = "ExceptionData", s.baseData.exceptions = [{ typeName: "SDKLoadFailed", message: t.replace(/\./g, "-"), hasFullStack: !1, stack: t + "\nSnippet failed to load [" + n + "] -- Telemetry is disabled\nHelp Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128109\nHost: " + (S && S.pathname || "_unknown_") + "\nEndpoint: " + o, parsedStack: [] }], a)), p.push((s = i, t = c, (o = (n = m(r, "Message")).data).baseType = "MessageData", (a = o.baseData).message = 'AI (Internal): 99 message:"' + ("SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details) (" + s + ")").replace(/\"/g, "") + '"', a.properties = { endpoint: t }, n)), i = p, r = c, JSON && ((o = v.fetch) && !T.useXhr ? o(r, { method: N, body: JSON.stringify(i), mode: "cors" }) : XMLHttpRequest && ((s = new XMLHttpRequest).open(N, r), s.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"), s.send(JSON.stringify(i))))) } function i(e, t) { d || setTimeout(function () { !t && g.core || a() }, 500) } f && ((n = y.createElement(k)).src = f, !(o = T[w]) && "" !== o || "undefined" == n[w] || (n[w] = o), n.onload = i, n.onerror = a, n.onreadystatechange = function (e, t) { "loaded" !== n.readyState && "complete" !== n.readyState || i(0, t) }, e = n, T.ld < 0 ? y.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e) : setTimeout(function () { y.getElementsByTagName(k)[0].parentNode.appendChild(e) }, T.ld || 0)); try { g.cookie = y.cookie } catch (h) { } function t(e) { for (; e.length;)!function (t) { g[t] = function () { var e = arguments; u || g.queue.push(function () { g[t].apply(g, e) }) } }(e.pop()) } var s, r, o = "track", c = "TrackPage", p = "TrackEvent", o = (t([o + "Event", o + "PageView", o + "Exception", o + "Trace", o + "DependencyData", o + "Metric", o + "PageViewPerformance", "start" + c, "stop" + c, "start" + p, "stop" + p, "addTelemetryInitializer", "setAuthenticatedUserContext", "clearAuthenticatedUserContext", "flush"]), g.SeverityLevel = { Verbose: 0, Information: 1, Warning: 2, Error: 3, Critical: 4 }, (l.extensionConfig || {}).ApplicationInsightsAnalytics || {}); return !0 !== l[I] && !0 !== o[I] && (t(["_" + (s = "onerror")]), r = v[s], v[s] = function (e, t, n, a, i) { var o = r && r(e, t, n, a, i); return !0 !== o && g["_" + s]({ message: e, url: t, lineNumber: n, columnNumber: a, error: i, evt: v.event }), o }, l.autoExceptionInstrumented = !0), g }(T.cfg)); function a() { T.onInit && T.onInit(n) } (v[t] = n).queue && 0 === n.queue.length ? (n.queue.push(a), n.trackPageView({})) : a() }(window, document, {
       src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js",

       crossOrigin: "anonymous",

       cfg: {
           connectionString: "InstrumentationKey=******;IngestionEndpoint=https://******.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://******.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
       }

   });

   window.appInsights = appInsights;
   appInsights.trackPageView();
   try {
       throw new Error("Logging Exception from Javascript");
   } catch (error) {
       appInsights.trackException("Logging Exception from Javascript.");
       appInsights.trackException({ error });
   }
</script>
```

```cs
appInsights.trackPageView();//For Logging Page Views
appInsights.trackException();//For Logging JS Exception
```

***Output:***

[image]

> "Failed to initialize AppInsights JS SDK: Cannot load Application Insights SDK,

- I have installed the same packages and version which you have provided(`.csproj`).
- I can see that the versions are deprecated.

[image]

Update all the packages to the latest version.

Comment: I will try this just one question: Is it ok to expose instrumentation key in the code? Or do I need to figure out a way to pull this in layout at runtime?

Comment: As you are running locally , just for testing I have exposed it.You can find a way to get it at runtime.

Comment: I will check locally and then need to implement a way to have it not exposed. Also I want to understand how much of a threat is it if instrumentation key of app setting is exposed

Comment: It is not recommended to expose it.

Comment: First try whether it is working even in local for you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I am yet to implement the solution suggested. I am not keeping very well. I will try as soon as possible from my end to check and confirm the solution. I appreciate the patience being shown by Harshitha, You and the rest of the community.

Comment: Like we discussed before we do not want the connection string exposed, Is there any ways I can explore how to achieve that? Any suggestions?